# Service Management Url in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-diagnostics

I'm trying to publish a cloud service from Visual Studio. Edit subscription dialog in Visual Studio asks me in the 4th step: **"Enter a service management URL"**. It's https://management.core.windows.net/ by default. What do I have to write there?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is what it should be unless you're running your own data center with your own management API hosted there

Comment: It means, I don't have to change it?